# Timetable Format in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to display the timetable from database with specific format in which one timeslot may have two or more labs for two or more batches, so the problem I am facing is when I place a lab on 8 to 10 on Monday and then when I try to place a lab on 9 to 11 on Tuesday then a new timeslot is being created instead of merging and using old cell.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100% height:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Timings</th>
                <th scope="col">Monday</th>
                <th scope="col">Tuesday</th>
                <th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
                <th scope="col">Thursday</th>
                <th scope="col">Friday</th>
            </tr>
            
            
            
        </thead>           
        <tbody>
            
            <tr>
            <?php $starting = 1;
                    $day = 1;
            foreach ($table as $value) {


                if($starting == 1){ 
                        $end=(int)$value->end_time - 1;
                        ?>
                        <th scope="row">{{$value->start_time." to ".$value->end_time}}</th>
                        
                        <?php if($day < $value->day_timetable){
                            for($i=$day; $i<($value->day_timetable-1); $i++) { ?>
                            <td></td>
                        <?php } }
                        $end= (double)$value->end_time;
                        $end= $end - 2;
                        if($value->start_time == $end)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <td rowspan="2">{{$value->subject_name."-".$value->faculty_name."(".$value->room_lectlab_no.")-".$value->batch_table}}<br>
                            <?php 
                        }else{
                            ?>
                            <td rowspan="2">{{ $value->subject_name."-".$value->faculty_name."(".$value->room_lectlab_no.")"}}
                                    <br>
                        
                    <?php 
                    
                        }
                    

                    $prev = $value->start_time;
                    $day = $value->day_timetable;
                    $starting = 0; 
                    
                }elseif($prev == $value->start_time && $day ==$value->day_timetable ){
                    ?>
                    {{$value->subject_name."-".$value->faculty_name."(".$value->room_lectlab_no.")"."-".$value->batch_table}}
                   <?php

                }else{ 
                    if($prev == $value->start_time){ 
                       if($day < $value->day_timetable){
                            for($i=$day+1; $i<$value->day_timetable; $i++) { ?>
                            <td></td> 
                        <?php } }
                        $end= (double)$value->end_time;
                        $end= $end - 2;
                        if($value->start_time == $end)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <td rowspan="2">{{$value->subject_name."-".$value->faculty_name."(".$value->room_lectlab_no.")-".$value->batch_table}}<br>
                            <?php 
                            }else{
                        ?>
                                <td rowspan="2">{{ $value->subject_name."-".$value->faculty_name."(".$value->room_lectlab_no.")"}}
                                    <br>
                        
                    <?php 
                    }
                   $prev = $value->start_time;
                        $day = $value->day_timetable;
                        
                    } else { $day = 1; ?>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="width: 100% height: 100%">
                        </tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowspan="2">{{$value->start_time." to ".$value->end_time}}</th>
                        <?php if($day < $value->day_timetable){
                                for($i=$day; $i<$value->day_timetable; $i++) { ?>
                            <td></td>
                        <?php } }$end= (double)$value->end_time;
                        $end= $end - 2;
                        if($value->start_time == $end)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <td rowspan="2">{{$value->subject_name."-".$value->faculty_name."(".$value->room_lectlab_no.")-".$value->batch_table}}<br>
                            <?php 
                        }else{
                        ?>
                                <td rowspan="2">{{ $value->subject_name."-".$value->faculty_name."(".$value->room_lectlab_no.")"}}
                                    <br>
                        
                    <?php 
                        }       
                            $prev = $value->start_time;
                            $day = $value->day_timetable;

                    } 
                } 
            } ?>
            
       
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9u5t.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is - aren't 8-10 Monday and 9-11 Tuesday different time slots? Also, what's with all the php tags? This would be a lot more simple to read if you used blade syntax

Comment: Maybe use a ready-made calendar UI instead of building your own. Then all you have to do is feed it the data, and it will take care of displaying it (although you can still configure some options to affect it too). e.g. this one is quite good: https://fullcalendar.io/docs, but there are others too